# C# MouseKeyHook: Certain Key + Modifier Combinations Not Working

Tags: c#, keyboard-events, mousekeyhook

I've been working with the MouseKeyHook NuGet package, and it's working great for capturing most input. But I'm having some problems catching certain combinations of keys + modifiers.

```
public static class InputHandler
{
    private static IKeyboardMouseEvents _GlobalHook;
    public static IKeyboardMouseEvents GlobalHook => _GlobalHook;

    public static void Subscribe()
    {
        _GlobalHook = Hook.AppEvents();
        _GlobalHook.KeyDown += KeyDown;
    }

    private static void KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Output: " + e.Modifiers + " + " + e.KeyCode);
    }
}
```

Lets try hitting a few keys and see what the output is:

```
Key: A
> Output: None + A

Key: Shift & A
> Output: Shift + A

Key: Shift & Control & Alt & A
> Output: Shift, Control, Alt + A
```

Fantastic! Exactly what you'd expect. Now what about the number bar at the top of the keyboard?

```
Key: 1
> Output: None + D1

Key: Shift & Control & Alt & 3
> Output: Shift, Control, Alt + D3
```

Okay, again, exactly what you'd expect. No problems...
What about the 0 key?

```
Key: 0
> Output: None + D0

Key: Shift & 0
> Output: Shift + D0

Key: Shift & Control & 0
> Output: Shift, Control + ShiftKey    <---- What????

Key: Shift & Control & Alt & 0
> Output: Shift, Control, Alt + D0
```

So what's going on here? Why does the event not fire properly when *exactly* D0 + Control + Shift is pressed? Also worth noting is that this is a KeyDown event, so the output repeats as long as you have the keys held down, but when that "ShiftKey" output is printed it never repeats, which is... odd.

Worst case, I can always switch up my bindings, but I've noticed this oddity over a number of different keys + modifier combinations (mostly oem keys, the numpad, and numbar), so it would be nice to know why this happens.

Comment: You got a notification when the ShiftKey was pressed, that's normal.  You can't assume that every combination is available.  There are other apps that use RegisterHotKey() to listen to keystrokes, commonly anything with Ctrl+Shift.  Those keys get hijacked before you can see them.  Intel shovelware is notably notorious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of two possibilities:

It could be an operating system keyboard shortcut.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/967893/input-method-editor-keyboard-shortcut-ctrl-shift-0-switches-the-input

Many keyboards are not physically capable of correctly detecting every possible combination of keys. The exact details vary depending on how the keyboard's circuit board is laid out. Shift-A or Ctrl-X will always work, holding down every key at once only works on the fanciest of keyboards, in between there's a grey area.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollover_(key)#Key_jamming_and_ghosting